# Parse Promises in Cloud Code / Express.js

Tags: express, parse-platform, promise

I have a simple function in Parse Cloud Code (with express.js), but I'm having trouble understanding the propagation of `Parse.Promise.error()` in this context.  When I hit the function, it returns nothing and the console says "success/error was not called."  Shouldn't the error be caught?

```js
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend('TestObject');
  query = new Parse.Query(TestObject);
  query.first().then(function(rr) {
    return Parse.Promise.error();
    res.send('should not reach this');
  }, function(error) {
    res.send('error');
  });
});
```

Comment: The error handler that goes into `then` does only handle errors in the promise (`query.first()`), not errors in the success handler. Chain an extra `.catch()` (or `then()`) on the returned promise.

Comment: This did it.  Thanks, @Bergi.  Sorry for the duplicate question.

Comment: No need to be sorry, it's not an obvious issue :-) Just wanted to avoid repeating the whole explanation.